# Bulk insert does not insert all the rows from the log file without giving any error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i'm using the following code

```
create TABLE #temp1(                                          
 [date] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [time] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [s-ip] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [cs-method] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [cs-uri-stem] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [cs-uri-query] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [s-port] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [cs-username] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [c-ip] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [cs(User-Agent)] [varchar](2048) NULL,
 [cs(Referer)] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [sc-status] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [sc-substatus] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [sc-win32-status] [varchar](500) NULL,
 [time-taken] [varchar](500) NULL
 )

BULK INSERT #temp1 FROM 'C:\iislogs\u_ex150108.log'
  WITH (
           FIRSTROW  = 5,

          FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ',
           ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
           MAXERRORS = 10000
        )
```

and the file that, i'm using has 1521000 lines but i am getting only  1305226 in #temp1

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're setting MAXERRORS = 10000.  Could it it be that you are hitting 10000 errors which would cause you to stop at 1305226?

Comment: Hi Bert i added MAXERRORS = 10000 after all that i tried in it. But it also does not give the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your valuable answer

But again after long search in Google.

I found one solution ,that this is a Microsoft sql server bug

This bug can only be solved when we install latest service pack of sql server in our system

And when I have installed service pack in my system bulk insert works well.

For any further help please take help from below link

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/837401/EN-US

Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

set all varchar to max and do the bulkfiles again, and please can you paste your log file to excel and see if the total row is really 1521000?

The problem usually caused by invalid fieldterminator and rowterminator.

Comment: I have opened the file in notepad+ and it's showing 1521000 lines.And also i checked the  fieldterminator and rowterminator. And i thing that  fieldterminator and rowterminator is also correct.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Could you give me the txt files?

Comment: Sorry, late to read your answer. So it seems the Sql Machine error, thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had an issue inserting rows with bulk insert, I added a rowcount condition till the stored procedure has to run.

```
select @tablerowcount = count(*) from tbl1
while @tablerowcount = 0
begin
  exec sp_custombulkinsert
end
```